# Uncaught exception 'Zend_View_Exception' with message 'script 'error/error.phtml'

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks, zend-view

When I nave some exception in my Zend Framework application, I see this error message:

```
Uncaught exception 'Zend_View_Exception' with message 'script 'error/error.phtml' not found in path (C:\wamp\www\my_app\application/views/)' in
```

If I move error/error.phtml in "view" folder, all work fine.

And I can't understand  why zend search error.phtml file in "view" folder, not in "view/scripts" folder.

Please Help

Comment: Check view->getScriptPaths(). What it shows?

Answer (score 0):

You can add below code to your bootstrap so it won't check for error.phtml.

```
$oFrontController->throwExceptions(true);
```